# Laptop battery AC connected but not charging

Tags: laptop

I bought a new laptop last week (ASUS N551VW) I noticed something weird when I'm charging it, whenever it reaches 98% it doesn't charge until I unplug it until it reaches 90 something and then it charges until 98% and takes forever to reach 100% ( it does reach it eventually) but then according to BatteryCare or BatteryViewInfo it's discharging and if I'm doing basic internet browsing it will not lose much power but when I use something heavier like gaming or VM emulating, it will start discharging more and the battery indicator will go down within time from 100% to 99 and then to 90 something and charge again? this is a brand new laptop and and a merely a week old and the battery wear is already 0.8 %, is this normal or should I return it? I don't want the hassle of the warranty if this issue is normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely isn't anything to worry about. As the battery gets almost full, the charger will switch to "trickle charge" mode, or it may stop charging at all. This is done to preserve the life of the battery, and to reduce the amount of power you use. When a battery is dead it can charge a lot faster than it can when it's full. So charging from 0% to 80% will go a lot faster than 80% to 100%.

Apps like BatteryCare may show it as discharging at that time because it simply doesn't read trickle charging correctly, or because the charger is actually cycling on and off.

Everything is working as it should based on what you described. You don't have anything to worry about!